# Using Mootools to prevent overlapping with random absolute positioning

Tags: javascript, css, mootools, positioning, absolute

I have over 50 simple text messages in a database and I extract them (using PHP) and place them randomly on a page using absolute positioning. Unfortunately some of these messages overlap each other, that I wish to prevent.

Can I use MooTools to find the position of each of these elements and their dimensions so that the new element to be placed on the page won't overlap any of the previous ones?

Using MooTools 1.3 with all core functions.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Element.getCoordinates()](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element.Dimensions#Element%3agetCoordinates) to get the coordinates and dimensions of your elements.

In your markup you could have a class i.e. `message` on each message element for the purpose of selection, and a class `hidden` that sets CSS `visibility: hidden` on all the messages.

On `domready` you would then do some simple boundary detection to detect overlapping messages and once you've avoided overlapping you can remove the `hidden` classes to draw the messages on the page.

Comment: How would I go about boundary detection and then avoiding overlapping? I like your idea of making the messages visible after changing the positioning to prevent the overlapping.

Comment: Can you show what HTML & CSS you have so far? Use jsfiddle.net so that we can tweak the code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to comment on this question, probably because I asked it as a "guest" and now I am registered.

My HTML/CSS is extremely simple. http://jsfiddle.net/bDDLt/

PHP does the calculations for the positions and styles and places these variables into the element styles. The values in the jsfiddle are examples (since it doesn't accept PHP)